Retrieving data from MySQL using VBA, trying to do using Persistent connection
My attempt at a Persistent connection from info I can find online. the connection is established when I open the workbook, but when I try retrieve data or close the workbook I get an error stating object required.
My connection code
Public objcnn As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub MySQL_Login()
    Set objcnn = New ADODB.Connection
    objcnn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 9.1 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost; Database=******; UID=******; PWD=******"
       
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    MySQL_Login
    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

'    objcnn.Close
    
End Sub

When I run the following piece of code from a user form it fails on line 2
    If ReportCon.Mpa_R.value <> "" And count = "1" Then
                                        Set objRmp = objcnn.Execute("select * from con_res_hed where mpa = '" & mparep & "' and date_cast >= '" & startdate & "' and date_cast <= '" & enddate & "' order by report_nr;")
                                        Sheets("ReportCon").Range("A8").CopyFromRecordset objRmp
                                        Set objRmp = objcnn.Execute("Select  weight1_7, weight2_7, weight3_7, dens1_7, dens2_7, dens3_7, mpa1_7, mpa2_7, mpa3_7, mpaA_7, weight1_28, weight2_28, weight3_28, dens1_28, dens2_28, dens3_28, mpa1_28, mpa2_28, mpa3_28, mpaA_28 " & _
                                                            "From con_res_data " & _
                                                            "Left join con_res_hed on con_res_data.report_nr = con_res_hed.report_nr " & _
                                                            "Where con_res_hed.mpa = '" & mparep & "' and date_cast >= '" & startdate & "' and date_cast <= '" & enddate & "' " & _
                                                            "Order by con_res_hed.report_nr;")
                                        Sheets("ReportCon").Range("L8").CopyFromRecordset objRmp
                                        ReportCon.Mpa_R.value = ""
                                        ReportCon.Start_date.value = ""
                                        ReportCon.End_Date.value = ""
                                        ReportCon.Rep_search.Enabled = False
                                        ReportCon.Report_Num.SetFocus
                                    Else



You did not show it, so I'm going to ask:  You do know that you have to declare objcnn   As Object  in the same module as your code, but outside any procedure in that module?  That's how you make that object persistent outside your procedure calls.

Does it help with your issue? public variable available in userform

I got it to work by declaring objcnn in a module called Variables that I created and added a few other global variables, when I tried declaring it in ThisWorkbook it did not want to work.
